# How to create Nested Models & Collections (sub collections)

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm just starting with Backbone.js and I am having trouble with nested models and collections.

For this example, I only have a single endpoint, `/vocabulary.json`.

Here is a sample of what that will return:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "words": [
        {
            "native": "hello",
            "foreign": "hola"
        },
        {
            "native": "yes",
            "foreign": "si"
        },
        {
            //... More words in this lesson
        }
    ]
},
{
    //... More lessons coming from this endpoint
}
]
```

It's basically of collection of `lessons`, and each `lesson` has a collection of vocabulary `words`.

How could I create a `words` collection without another `url` endpoint (required by collections, it seems)?

Here's what I have so far. Actually, this is a stripped down, basic version because everything I'm trying isn't working.

**/entities/vocabulary.js**

```
Entities.Vocabulary = Backbone.Model.extend({});

Entities.Vocabularies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Entities.Vocabulary,
    url: "/vocabulary.json"
});

// Here is where I am struggling

Entities.Vocabulary.Word = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // what to do?
});

Entities.Vocabulary.Words = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // what to do?
    // Need some method to go into the Entities.Vocabularies Collection, pluck a given id
    // and return the "words" attribute as a new Collection to work from.
});
```

Perhaps, I am thinking about this completely wrong, but I am hoping I have explained my problem well enough to help you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there. You can use `parse` method on the model where you can write up your logic of associating the  words collection to the vocabulary model.. Something in these lines.

```
// This would be your main Model
// Set the idAttribute on it
// Use the parse method here which hits before initialize
// where you attach the words collection on each Vocabulary  Model
Entities.Vocabulary = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute : 'id',
    parse: function (response) {
        // If theresponse has wods in response
        // attach it words collection to the Vocabulary Model
        if (response.words) {
           this.words = new Entities.Vocabulary.Words(response.words || null, {
               parse: true
           });
        }
        // Delete the words object from response as the collection is already 
        // created on the model
        delete response.words;

        return response;
    }
});

// Collection of Vocabulary
Entities.Vocabularies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Entities.Vocabulary,
    url: "/vocabulary.json"
});

// This would be the model for Word inside a Specific Vocabulory
// Associate a idAttribute if it has one.
// Add a parse method if you have any other extra processing for this model
Entities.Vocabulary.Word = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

// Just a Collection of words for the vocabulory
Entities.Vocabulary.Words = Backbone.Collection.extend({

});


// Pass the object, and pass in the parse: true 
// parameter so that parse is called before initialize
var vocabularies = new Entities.Vocabularies(navi, {
    parse: true
});

// If you want to fetch a new collection again you would just do 

//vocabularies.fetch({parse: true});


console.log(mainCollection);
```

So each model should have a words collection directly on the Vocabulary model.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ySKQW/2/)**